How to reduce size of canvas.toJSON(); with imported images
So I am creating a product configurator using fabric js and users can import images and add it in canvas so to save their work im using canvas.toJSON to save their work in database as json but it's too big especially if they add multiple images and the database will be laggy though this is expected, Im still thinking if I use blob instead and save the file name in the database instead. I supposed to use canvas.loadFromJson and just use the json from database.
Is it possible to compress canvas.toJSON() even more specially if the objects includes imported images? or is it common that projects like this will easily eat storage?

You can solve it via canvas.toDatalessJSON() method.
This method can change a canvas to JSON with a smaller capacity than canvas.toJSON(), and can also be loaded through the canvas.loadFromJSON() method.
However, when using this method, user-defined properties other than default properties are not saved. In order to save, you must pass the property name as an array argument to this method.
An example of use is as follows:
// 'originWidth', 'originHeight' are user-defined properties.
const properties = ['originWidth', 'originHeight']
const canvasJSON = canvas.toDatalessJSON(properties)

You can check more details on the official site below.
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toDatalessJSON
I hope it was helpful to you. thank you.
